# "P1: begin" and "P2: begin" in a DB2 Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, sql-pl

Can anyone explain to me or point me to some documentation on why the stored procedures are tagged into different parts using "P1: begin" and "P2: begin" ?
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Too vague. And what procedures?

Answer (score 1):

An SQL Procedure is defined by the *routine-body*.  The *routine-body* is defined by\as **one** SQL Statement, which for a SQL Procedure is typically defined by one *compound-statement*, yet a *compound-statement* may be nested within another.  Each `label:Begin` establishes the beginning of a new compound statement; one defined within another would be a *nested* compound statement.  The following is a doc link that may satisfy as an answer to the question; a doc snippet is included which describes the primary purpose as *scoping*, and I added emphasis on each entity that is scoped:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzsummaryscope.htm

> **Summary of ′name′ scoping in nested compound statements**
>   
>   Nested compound statements can be used within an SQL routine to define the scope of SQL **variable declarations**, **cursors**, **condition names**, and **condition handlers**.
>   
>   Additionally, **labels** have a defined scope in the context of nested compound statements. However the rules for name space, and how non-unique names can be referenced, differs depending on the type of name. The following table summarizes these differences.
>   [...]